# What is the most appropriated and secure way to encrypt files using private/public keys in Node.js

Tags: node.js, encryption, public-key-encryption, private-key, public-key

I was wondering in which use case i should use these methods when encrypting and decrypting files in my node.js application.

## The Problem

I want to encrypt some files in my server, after asking other people, i realized that the most recommended method is encrypt those files (larges) using a private key.

Now, i was looking for the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_privateencrypt_privatekey_buffer) and saw these methods

- `crypto.publicEncrypt(pubKey, buffer)`
- `crypto.publicDecrypt(pubKey, buffer)`
- `crypto.privateEncrypt(privKey, buffer)`
- `crypo.privateDecrypt(privKey, buffer)`

this is very confusing because i don't know what of them i must to use now, ahm... i don't know what is the most appropriate way to do this securely.

Comment: Cryptography is unfortunately complicated, and unqualified statements like "the most recommended method is *XYZ*" are not things an expert would ever say. It depends on your system, your access model, and your threat model. It may be the simple password-based cryptography is correct for your needs, or perhaps not. A further problem is that the API you are looking at is hopelessly low-level and requires an expert to properly use. You should look for a higher-level API with a good reputation.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** encrypt with the public key. Keep your private key safe.

Unfortunately, these methods are poorly named. `privateEncrypt` should be called something like `sign` and `publicDecrypt` should be called something like `verify`.

When using public-key encryption (also known as asymmetric encryption), one key can be used to write a cipher and the other key can undo that operation. Your public key is potentially known to everyone, and your private key is secret.

If you want to keep something secret, except from the owner of a certain key, you want to encrypt a message with *their* public key. So if Alice wants to receive encrypted messages, she'll share her public key `A_pub` and her secret key `A_priv`, she'll keep to herself.. You'll encrypt your message `crypto.publicEncrypt(A_pub, buffer)`. She'll then decrypt that message with `crypto.privateDecrypt(A_priv, buffer)`.

Doing it the other way is known as a [**digitial signature**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature).

Comment: when i try to encrypt the file using the public key, it says the content is too long for this cipher.

Comment: In short, You should prefer hybrid encryption. Create a random key for the symmetric encryption (like AES) for the file, then encrypt, send the file with the key which is encrypted with the public key of the receiver. See, [sealedboc](https://github.com/whs/tweetnacl-sealed-box)